# I am trying to merge two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe

```
firm          formtype  Date_Filed
GameStop Corp.  8-K     2021-04-01
```

I want to change the `Date_Filed` to `2021-04-01 00:00:00`.

I am using `pd.to_datetime(df2['Date_Filed'])` but it is not working

Comment: How is changing the format of the contents of one column in one dataframe "merging" it with another — please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you meant by merge two dataframes but if all you want is to change the date format of your column, you can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'firm': {0: 'GameStop Corp.'},'formtype': {0: '8-K'},'Date_Filed': {0: '2021-04-01'}})
df['Date_Filed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Filed'])
df['Date_Filed1'] = df['Date_Filed'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %h:%m%s')
```